# nopCommerce sample data delete

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nopcommerce

I want to clean up sample data of [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) 2.65. I don't want to re-install it.
If anybody have some idea or script then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - it is based off an older script I found from another user.  I too enjoy the ability to use the sample data during development, but I needed a way to remove all the products/orders/etc. prior to going live.  The problem with recreating a new database is that I lose all my settings, custom text/languages/etc. which I want to keep.  I just want to get rid of the products and orders.

Here is the post I made on the NopCommerce Boards:
http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/23464/delete-sample-data.aspx#103867

*Feel free to comment if I missed anything!*